# Anchor tag's hotspot attributes not working in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

So, the thing is I created some kind of a map on a website. Whenever you hover with your mouse over the cities located on the map, you cross a hotspot zone that enables a pop box to appear and give information about the team that's located in the concerned city. In firefox it works beautifully well, but in Chrome it doesn't seem to detect the hotspot created by anchor tag's attributes.

The pop box defined within the html index

```
<div id="pop1" class="popbox">
   <h2>Youth Academy Bucuresti</h2>
   <p>Membri:</p>
</div>
[...] more pop boxes [...]
```

The map

```
<img src="images/first_try.png" usemap="#yaro" style="margin-bottom: 100px;">
<map name="yaro">
   <a shape="rect" coords="355,375,425,403" href="#" class="popper" data-popbox="pop1"></a>
[...] more anchor tags [..]
</map>
```

Any ideas why while browsing the website using Chrome, the hotspots are not detected? Might it be because the attributes "shape", "coords" aren't yet officialy supported by HTML5?

How it looks in Firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5XQw.jpg (my cursor was over the city Piatra Neamt)

Answer (score 0):

Use `area` tags intead of `a`.

Seems to work for me http://codepen.io/elliz/pen/FgeqE

```
<h2>Test with `area` tags</h2>

<img usemap="#area" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKAAAABaAQMAAAAFCM8RAAAABlBMVEX/DAD/45HIkMgSAAAAIklEQVR4XmMYsmAU1P8HgwPMEPrf8BQcFRwVHBUcqmAUAACXrqnfUify7gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="/>

<map name="area" id="area">
  <area shape="rect" title="Left box" href="#" coords="17,21,73,68" />
  <area shape="rect" title="right box" href="#" coords="86,21,142,68" />
</map>
```

Comment: It's all 'cause a's "coords" and "shape" attributes are obsolete in HTML5. Dunno why Firefox still uses them, but Chrome doesn't.

Comment: Though I would consider using positioned `a` tags as there may be issues with image maps on mobile devices ... how would your page work very narrow? would you prefer a list rather than the map of Romania?

Answer (score 0):

Tried before with "area" tags, but it wasn't working 'cause I forgot to change something in the pop-up javascript file. Now it's all fine.
Regarding the website on narrow desktops, mhm, a list seems fine, but I'll see what the other members of the organisation think about it, as they've wanted for a long time a representation of this kind(Romania's map with the cities involved in the organisation).